# Authorize.Net Customize Field?

Tags: php, cakephp, payment-gateway

i am trying to integrate Authrize.net API AIM Method for Web Application in PHP platform i want to added customize field in my form i.e Billing Address & Other Personal Information & Also Create My Own Receipt can any one guide me how can i achieved this goal?

Comment: A note for you, in case you didn't know: CAPS are considered shouting and impolite. If you did know it's even worse. Some netiquette goes a long way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Billing address, and other personal information fields are not custom fields. They are built into the API so there is no need to create custom fields for them.
2. If you want to use custom fields information all you need to do is submit a
   custom field name and any accompanying text with the transaction request string. See page 34 of the [AIM Guide](http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/AIM_guide.pdf) for more information on this.
3. Creating your receipt is no different them creating your own web page or creating your own email. Once you get a successful response from Authorize.Net you can show the receipt and/or send your own receipt via email.

Comment: The "AIM Guide" link appears broken.

Comment: @NickRolando Thanks for letting me know. I've updated with a direct link to the file.